# DDD - Repository and many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I am new to DDD and I am stuck here:
I have a many-to-many relationship between two entities: User and Group. The relationship is not an Aggregate because a User can exist without a Group and a Group can exist without a User.

This is my code for the User class:

```
public class User {

    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();
    
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void create() throws Exception{
        userRepository.create(this);        
        
        // I have to update the groups with the user.
        for (Group group : groups) {
            group.update();
        }
    }
    
     public void addGroup(Group group){
        if (!groups.contains(group)) {
            groups.add(group);
            group.addUser(this);
         }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know where to associate those classes when I create a User who has groups in (I cannot use ORM). I made it in the create method of User, and I also manage transactions there through Spring. Is this correct? Or should I put that code in the userRepository or in a Service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I made it in the create method of User, and also manage transactions there through Spring. Is this correct?

Correctness of this logic would depend on how the repository is written and it's contract. If the repository will not persist any relationships, then it could be a sign of a poorly designed repository. I would expect a repository to implement the necessary logic to store entity associations as well, and not just the simple properties of the entity.

A repository based on an ORM solution would have made this easier by through the cascading of persistence events, but in your case, it might lead to duplication of code in both your repositories (I am assuming that you have a `GroupRepository` as well). It might be better if you decide on which entity owns the relationship, and then have the association persisted by the corresponding repository. Any changes in the association should therefore be done only by the entity that owns the association (it appears to be `User` in your case, and by inference the `UserRepository` should manage the association).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean that I have to move the update of the groups inside the UserRepository? In that case UserRepository has to see GroupRepository?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that you have to move the update. I meant that if you persist a `User` using `userRepository.create()`, then the repository should "inspect" the `User` instance and create the associations in the persistence store (depending on how persistence is handled). This is if the `User` entity owns the relationship. If the `Group` owns the relationship, then the `GroupRepository` should be doing this; it should inspect the `Group` instance and manage the associations with the `User` instances. The same goes for any update/modify methods exposed by the repository. (Contd).

Comment: You'll notice why the concept of aggregate roots is important for repositories - the repository for the aggregate root is the only domain object that worries about all associations. In a M:M relationship like yours, you would typically have two repositories as each of the domain entities happen to be aggregate roots. But you would want to manage the relationship only in one repository, if you want to avoid duplicating the logic, and that's why you would choose an owner for the relationship.

Answer (score 3):

According Eric Evans' book, many to many associations make your model too complex. Try to replace them with
2 many-to-one associations. One part of many-to-many association always has more
business value than other.

In your case I would stay with 2 aggregates - `User` and `Group`, where `User` aggregate is responsible for holding bunch of `GroupReferences`.

Comment: Agree.  See linked example, although the context is ORM.  Udi's approach is not to choose the more valuable relationship, it's to hold the relationship on the entity that is dependent on the other entity.  In your case, that's group.  http://udidahan.com/2009/01/24/ddd-many-to-many-object-relational-mapping/

Answer (score 1):

Lucas, I would:

1) Create a User factory that can take in the Groups that should be associated with the new User. The factory can use the addGroup method to make that association.

2) Remove your reference to the UserRepository from the User class.